# What component should I use to draw a dendrogram in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, dendrogram

Dendrogram is not a regular diagram. Should I use any component from javax.swing.* library, or just draw it with java.awt.Graphics?

Answer (score 2):

Might also be worth checking: [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html) and [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard component for this. Unless some component vendor has done one, you should go the Java 2D way...

If you don't want to do the hard work, perhaps one of the above mentioned libraries might help you. Otherwise, GraphViz is good at making this kind of diagram, and has a [Java API](http://www.loria.fr/~szathmar/off/projects/java/GraphVizAPI/index.php) (untested...).

Another possible way is to use some physics to let the nodes arrange themselves in an harmonious way. That's how [Aharef's HTML graph](http://www.aharef.info/static/htmlgraph/) works...

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans Graphing API](http://graph.netbeans.org/)

By far the easiest and most intuitive API of the lot.